# Change model name in browser rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model in rails and I called it `free_mess`

And my routes file contain `resources :free_mess`

Obviously this model name is not ideal to show in the browser, it shows up like this:

```
localhost:3000/free_mess/show
localhost:3000/free_mess/index
localhost:3000/free_mess/message1
```

I need to change the `free_mess` in the browser to something more readable like `'messages'`. So that the browser shows this:

```
localhost:3000/messages/show
localhost:3000/messages/index
localhost:3000/messages/message1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :free_mess, path: 'messages'
```

This will add alias routes in your app.

But if you want to rename the path **AND** the shhelper methods, then you should do:

```
resources :stories, :path => :books, :as => :books
```

See: [Overriding the Named Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

**Do this in config/routes.rb**

**To get this**

```
localhost:3000/messages/show
localhost:3000/messages/index
localhost:3000/messages/message1
```

**Do this**

```
get 'messages/show' => 'free_mess#show'
get 'messages/index' => 'free_mess#index'
get 'messages/message1' => 'free_mess#message1'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a path option:

```
resources :free_mess, path: 'messages'
```